# Using AlarmManager, Intent.PutExtra only seems to work when the project is rebuilt

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent, alarmmanager

My Alarms are initialized as follows, using a custom defined Alarm class:

```
                    //j represents the day of the week, starting on sunday
                    Intent myIntent;
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

                    TimeSpan instTime = instAlarm.AlarmTime;

                    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.GetInstance(Resources.Configuration.Locale);
                    int year = currentDate.Get(CalendarField.Year);
                    int month = currentDate.Get(CalendarField.Month);
                    currentDate.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, j+1);
                    int day = currentDate.Get(CalendarField.DayOfMonth);


                    Calendar calInst = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, instTime.Hours, instTime.Minutes, 0);

                    myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));

                    myIntent.PutExtra("theName", instAlarm.Name);
                    myIntent.PutExtra("Description", instAlarm.Description);
                    myIntent.PutExtra("Gauntlet", instAlarm.Gauntlet);
                    myIntent.PutExtra("Daily", instAlarm.Daily);

                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, myIntent, 0);
                    manager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calInst.TimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

and then the gets the extra strings and booleans:

```
        string instName = intent.GetStringExtra("theName").ToString();
        string instDescription = intent.GetStringExtra("Description").ToString();
        bool Gauntlet = intent.GetBooleanExtra("Gauntlet", false);
        bool Daily = intent.GetBooleanExtra("Daily", false);


        Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, instName + "|" + instDescription, ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

So when I make an alarm, the first one displays the name and description correctly, but any alarms made after that display the same text as the first. This goes on even if the alarm is deleted, the app is closed and reopened, or if I exit and reenter debug mode. The only way I've found to change it is to rebuild the solution.

I'm not familiar with AlarmManager or Intents so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to set the flag as UpdateCurrent . `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT That helped with the original problem, however, I'd like to manage multiple alarms, but that PendingIntentFlag only keeps track of the most recent one. I tried using the other PendingIntentFlags but none of them seem to work. Is there any way to manage multiple PendingIntents?

Comment: Set the different requestCode .